# Scrollbar position after refreshing Datagridview vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, refresh

I am working on a system that will collect data from different computers.

My requirement is when I refresh the datagridview to view the input data in my database then the selected row should be selected and the scroll bar position should be at the same location, because when the refresh happens the scroll bar is moved to the top of the grid. Any help would be appreciated!

Im using this code to refresh the DataGridView

```
Private Sub Form_Load(sender As object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

RefreshData()
End Sub

Private Sub AutoRefresher_tick(sender As object, e As EventArgs) Handles AutoRefresher.Tick
DatagridView()
End Sub

Sub RefreshData()
Dim timer as new Timer
timer.Interval = 5000
addHandler timer.tick, Addressof AutoRefresher_Tick
timer.start()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

"Selection" is a bad term here because "selection" means something specific in a `DataGridView` and it's not what you need. The `SelectedRows` property is a collection of rows that are selected, i.e. highlighted. What matters here is where the caret is located and that is the "current" row, not the "selected" row. The `CurrentRow` property is a single row and it is the row that contains the `CurrentCell`, which is the cell that contains the caret.

What you need to do is get the `CurrentRow` before the refresh, store a unique identifier for that record, do the refresh, find the new row that contains that identifier and make that the current row. Ideally, you should be binding data via a `BindingSource` and then you can use the `Current` and `Position` property of that, e.g.

```vb
Dim currentRecord = DirectCast(BindingSource1.Current, DataRowView)
Dim currentId = currentRecord("Id")

'Refresh data here.

Dim position = BindingSource1.Find("Id", currentId)

BindingSource1.Position = position
```